# Change Layout of Product List Filtered with Product Tag

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-list, tags

Where can I change the layout of the Product List Page filtered by the Product Tag. Currently My layout would be 3 columns but I want to change it to 2 columns left sidebar. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your catalog.xml (app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\layout\catalog.xml) by adding this code below `<catalog_category_layered translate="label">` like this :

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
        </action>
    </reference>
    .....
```

If you can't find it in your catalog.xml, you can added in local.xml like this :

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
    </action>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

You can read more about layout change in here : [How to change default page layout](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-change-default-page-layout/)

Comment: You're welcome @Alen. I am glad to help. You can accept my answer by click the checklist icon :)